# What is a single word for "build and maintain"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've considered *grow* which doesn't quite fit the bill and neither does *nurture*. *Incubate* is probably wrong and seems a little too specialized for general usage anyway.

This is in the context of a business.

Eg. "Build and maintain new distribution channels"

Comment: "Estivation" is the summer equivalent of hibernation.  By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Is the word applying to men, animals, business or something else ? Are you looking for a verb as "thrive", "flourish" or "prosper" ? please, clarify your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Establish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/establish) maybe.

**establish**.

1. to bring into being on a firm or permanent basis; found; institute: to establish a university.
2. to cause to become regular or usual: established the habit of going to bed early.